# how to use Google Plus hangout API in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, google-hangouts

I am new at intergrating Google Plus API's in Salesforce..
I need a patience help to guide me through Oauth procedure and step by step solution to Schedule a Hangout through Salesforce..
Any help is greatly admirerd.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you ever done authentication using OAuth 2.0?

Comment: @Ashwin No, I didnt use OAuth 2.0 before..

Comment: Then you first need to go through OAuth flow. I am posting link...

Comment: ohks..thnks for ur help..

Comment: @Ashwin .Can u please post that link..

Answer (score 1):

- [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) is the process to do authentication with google and go [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) to look how to implement OAuth in Google. [This](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is the place to test your OAuth 2.0 implementation.
- From [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) you can start working with google hangout integration.
- Look in above point and try to look over the samples provided in different languages, also look over libraries provided by google e.g.; [this](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout) to make integration easier.